# Diagnostics and usage data option disabled?

Tags: windows

this is very annoying because all im trying to do is get windows 11 insider preview build. but this is stopping me from doing all that.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kcgys.png

Comment: Are you connected to a AD domain?  If you are not, is your local account, connected to a Microsoft Account.  I presume your system meets the requirements for Windows 11?

Comment: What is the value of *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\DataCollection*? Make sure Connected User Experiences and Telemetry is running

Comment: The message about being managed by an organization is due to having a required option disabled (don’t asked which one I don’t know off hand)