# I am not able to access preview settings

Tags: windows-10, privacy, windows-insider, windows-11-preview

I want to change settings to send optional data.
But it says it is controlled by an organization.
[image]

I tried changing using gpdedit but it still did not work.
I also tried enabling telemetry but it did not work.
I want to do this because then it will enable insider preview and then I can get windows 11.
Is there a solution?

Comment: Try a different user account. Make a new, test Windows User account (Profile). Make it a member of Administrators.   Log into the new Account and try the diagnostic settings again. I had not turned off the optional features so Insider Preview upgraded properly.

Comment: Similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1659600/diagnostics-and-usage-data-option-disabled#comment2541818_1659600).  You can have this question reopened by providing more information in order to properly diagnose your issue.  Be sure you [edit] the question instead of submitting a comment.  The more detailed the initial edit is the better the chances the question will be reopened

Comment: Hi @John Logged in from my new account

Comment: it stil is the same

Comment: @Ramhound trying it, will respond.

Comment: You might try running a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link.

Comment: Hey guys, ramhounds suggestion worked

Comment: I got my windows 11 from the answer in ramhounds question

Comment: John's suggestion helped